# How to rightly place a return Value in the recursive python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

I am traversing the children of a node in a binary tree and checking the `locked` property. Return `False` if any of the children lock state is `False` and `True` otherwise. I can't seem to find the right way to place the `return` statement in the code. Note that the input to the `lock` function is a node object.

```
class BinaryTree():
    def __init__(self, value, lock=False):
        self.locked = lock
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def lock(self, node_object):
        """lock a node if the descendants are locked using post-order traversing"""
        flag = True
        if node_object.left:
            if node_object.left.locked == True:
                print(
                    f'>>> Left child: {node_object.left.value}. Locked?: {node_object.left.locked} <<<')
                self.lock(node_object.left)
            else:
                flag = False
                print(
                    f'>>> Children Node: {node_object.left.value}\tstate: {node_object.left.locked}. Lock failed <<<')
        if node_object.right:
            if node_object.right.locked == True:
                print(
                    f'>>> Right child: {node_object.right.value}. Locked?: {node_object.right.locked} <<<')
                self.lock(node_object.right)
            else:
                flag = False
                print(
                    f'>>> Children Node: {node_object.right.value}\tstate: {node_object.right.locked}. Lock failed <<<')
        return flag

# test the functions
if __name__ == "__main__":
    BT = BinaryTree(None)
    count = 0
    lock_state = False
    nodes = [34, 2, 1, 6, 8, 9, 56, 99, 150, 45, 3]
    for item in nodes:
        BT.add_node(item, lock_state)  # test add_node
    node = BT.find_node(56)  # test find_node function
    if node is not None:
        status = BT.lock(node)
        print(status)
```

`status` is always `True`, even when the `else` statements are executed.

Comment: You have to and the left and right node together, or more efficiently, return immediately if either is False.

Comment: You also need to check the return value of the recursive call, out what's the point.

Comment: Why do you think you need a node as argument for lock? self should already be a node.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, anding left and right node together assumes that left and right must exist. A node may have only one leaf.

Comment: @Tarbo. A tree must end, so some nodes have no children. A comment is usually supposed to give you a place to start thinking, not provide the complete solution with all corner cases. That's your job to figure out and it looks like you're of to a good start.

Comment: @Tarbo. Also, just to clarify some terminology, a leaf is a node with no children. A parent node is by definition not a leaf, whether it has one child or two. A child may be a leaf or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the recursion right, let's look at the base case:

- If current node is unlocked, return False
- If `left` exists and is unlocked, return False
- If `right` exists and is unlocked, return False
- Return True

The checks on `left` and `right` should be done recursively:

```
def is_locked(self):
     return self.locked and (not self.left or self.left.is_locked()) and (not self.right or self.right.is_locked())
```

Since `and` and `or` are short-circuiting operators, only the trees that need to be checked are checked. Notice that we use the return values from the calls on the children, unlike your original code.

As per the comment, you can generalize this approach using the built-in `all`. While not especially useful for a binary tree, this approach generalizes well to arbitrary n-ary trees:

```
def is_locked(self):
    return self.locked and all(node.is_locked() for node in (self.left, self.right) if node)
```

An n-ary tree would likely have a mutable sequence attribute `self.children` instead of `(self.left, self.right)`.

Comment: I was about to write an answer to underline the fact that you can reword the statement as "return True only if all children are locked". This can then be written as `return self.locked and all(node.is_locked() if node else True for node in (self.left, self.right))`.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon It would be more efficient to disregard missing children entirely: `return self.lock and all(node.lock() for node in (self.left, self.right) if node)`

Comment: Right, that's even neater

Answer (score 1):

Every new call to a recursive function puts a new instance of that function on a stack, with its own copies of local variables.

You're trying to manipulate `flag` as if it is some global variable, but it is local to each called instance of `lock()`. Note that this is a good thing - what if you had multiple objects, they certainly shouldn't share the same `flag`. And changing `flag` to an attribute of the class would still be problematic in some cases.

You're on the right track, trying to return a result, but when you make the recursive calls with `self.lock()`, those calls will return the result for that section and you should therefore capture the return value and deal with it, as others have suggested.

i.e. `flag = self.lock(node_object.left)` instead of just calling `self.lock(node_object.left)`. I would suggest renaming `flag` to `result`, since that is really what it is: a variable that's holding the result.

As an improvement, instead of assigning the result to `flag` / `result` and returning it at the end - since you don't use `flag` anywhere except to return the result - you could just change all the `flag = <something>` statements to `return <something>` statements. There is no rule against having multiple return statements, although some purists may not like it for specific reasons.

Comment: This does a much better job of addressing OP's actual issue than my answer. +1